# Windows 7 Offline Folders - Folder Access when Offline

Tags: windows-7

In Windows XP, offline folders allowed you access to a folder even if it was offline. This meant you could merrily save your files in the offline location .. and when you were online again, the file got pushed to the server - into the server location you wanted.

With Windows 7, when you're offline, it doesn't even allow you to save files into the an offline folder like before - which is really annoying if you have to work offline, but don't want to take all my work folders offline with me.

Is this feature (which I thought was great) still available with Windows 7? If it is, how can I configure it?

Comment: Have you looked at the options in the sync centre? We had offline files the same in 7 as we did in XP a few years back...